# Sum of waves with random phase and amplitudes as random sum of cosines

Tags: probability, statistics

I need to derive the average and variance of the amplitude of a sum of waves with the form:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N e^{j\delta_k} A_k
$$
where 
$$A_k = \sum_{i=1}^N \cos(\phi_k - \phi_i)$$
The random variables $\delta$ and $\phi$ are independent and uniformly distributed. $\phi$ between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ and $\delta$ between an arbitrary constant $-\omega/2$ and $\omega/2$. Also, I can consider $N$ arbitrarily large.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for any help.